# Qustion about load balancers

Tags: networking, load-balancing

I'm using a lot of load balancers in my workplace and I was wondering if there is a good open source one?

By good I mean one that can be used in an enterprise, and also is it efficient to use that software with regular PC?

BTW, I've been searching the internet a lot and found a few but not sure which one is better than the other one, I need your expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAProxy and nginx are popular open source options:

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

http://www.nginx.com/

I recommend reading through the documentation for each one to get a sense of the capabilities.  HAProxy is more analogous to the network load balancers I suspect you're using at work, with full support for any application protocol layered over TCP.  Nginx is really an HTTP server, but it can be configured as a reverse proxy that load balances to back-end destination servers.  If you just need to load-balance HTTP traffic (and you don't need to route other network protocols like ssh or SMTP), then nginx can be a good fit.

Comment: Apache HTTPD also has a load balancing module.